# Local apt repository: Cannot find Release file in local apt repository

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, gnupg

How can I debug the following? I set up an APT repository on my local laptop to prevent repeated downloads from Vagrant test VMs that I spin up for testing. But when I run `sudo apt-get update` on my guests, I get the following error:

```
W: The repository 'http://host-laptop-ip/pkgs' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration detail.
```

I have already gone through the manpage, which is what helped me create the repo in the first place. This is what I did on the host:

1. Set up a web server (apache2) on my laptop, and put the packages I want under a virtual directory (/var/www/html/pkgs). In fact it's put under a specific path `/var/www/html/pkgs/dists/$(lsb_release -s -c)/main/binary-amd64`.
2. I generated a key pair using GnuPG, made the public key accessible via a file in the same virtual directory, signed the packages using this key by using `dpkg-sign`.
3. Generated the Packages, Release, and InRelease files under the `pkgs` and the `/var/www/html/pkgs/dists/$(lsb_release -s -c)/main/binary-amd64` directories *both*.

This is what I did on the guest:

1. I added the following line at the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

   ```
   deb [ arch=amd64 ] http<nolink>://laptop-host-ip/pkgs xenial main
   ```
2. And:

   ```
   wget -O http<nolink>://laptop-host-ip/pkgs/keyFile | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

I have described all the details in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amukherj/2b0ca55b7f750e9a89e7474e868a74dc).